# SQL: Store Calculated value of column and use it for further manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I Have a Table with `Id`,`Gross Amount` and `Amount Applied`.

```
ID | Gross Amt | Amt Applied | Outstanding Amount
1  |   100     |    10       |    90
1  |   100     |    10       |    80
1  |   100     |    10       |    70
```

How to get outstanding Amount value for each column for same id.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a column which can be used to order the rows of that result? Then this can easily be done using window functions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its Sql-Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes there is one Invoice_Number column which is unique and can identify each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a cumulative sum.  However, that depends on the ordering of the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Assuming you have such a column, you can use the ANSI-standard function for cumulative sums in most databases:

```
select t.*,
       (gross_amount - sum(amt_applied) over (partition by id order by ?)
       ) as outstanding_amount
from t;
```

The `?` is for the ordering column.